# How does the browser connect html class names and css style entries?

Tags: html, css, dom

HTML

```html
<a class="link cta"> link </a>
```

CSS

```css
.link, .cta, .blueText, .title{
  color: cyan;
}
```

The browser see the class names (`link`, `cta`) in html first then find the style in css and then apply the style.

Or

It see the class names (`.link`, `.cta`, `.blueText`, `.title`) in css first then find those class name in html and then apply the style.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/How_CSS_works Read it, its one of the first things when you google "process of browser applying css" It has relay easy to understand 6 points of process.

Comment: I don't know why people downgraded this question, maybe because of the qus title, if you are asking something which is already available then people should link or mark it as duplicate. Anyways, you must read how DOM Parser works and how it renders stuff.

Comment: @vikas Question is to wide and SO has guide-lines. Plenty of articles and documentation on this subject on google.

Comment: @ikiK A "too wide" questions means that there are **many** different answers that could apply (for instance just "How does a compiler work?"). If there are not many different answers that could apply then "too wide" is not a valid objection. There might be other valid objections like off-topic, etc but "too wide" is not one.

Comment: In this specific case the question is as narrow that it possibly can be, it basically boils down to asking "Does the browser do A or B?", to which someone answered "It does B". A literal text book example of something that does *not* have many different answers that could apply. Now the current question title by itself would qualify as too wide, but the solution is then to fix the question and edit the title (which I will do), not by closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's more like the second. Basically:

Not necessarily in this order:

- The browser parses the HTML and creates a bunch of objects called The Document Object Model, or DOM.
- The browser parses the CSS. Each CSS block is made up of a selector and then a bunch of properties.
- For each CSS block, the browser looks through the DOM for all the elements that match the selector and then applies the properties.

In your above example, the selector is a list of classes but there are other kinds of selectors.

Note that in real life things don't always work out in that simple order as things can be loaded late, etc.

Hopefully that is of some help...